# Why do I get the `div.setAttribute is not a function` error in my code?

Tags: javascript

I am getting the error:

> div.setAttribute is not a function

in the following code snippet:

```
FriendlyChat.prototype.displayMessage = function(key, name, text, picUrl, imageUri) {
  console.log('FriendlyChat.prototype.displayMessage');
  var div = document.getElementById(key);
  // If an element for that message does not exists yet we create it.
  if (!div) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.innerHTML = FriendlyChat.MESSAGE_TEMPLATE;
    div = container.firstChild;
    div.setAttribute('id', key);
    this.messageList.appendChild(div);
  }
  if (picUrl) {
    div.querySelector('.pic').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + picUrl + ')';
  }
  div.querySelector('.name').textContent = name;
  var messageElement = div.querySelector('.message');
  if (text) { // If the message is text.
    messageElement.textContent = text;
    // Replace all line breaks by <br>.
    messageElement.innerHTML = messageElement.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
  } 
};
```

The error occurs whenever the above function is called. I don't know what is wrong with the code.

Why does the error occur?

Comment: you need to add a bit more context, on what html, what should it do? Is this homework?

Comment: That line is redundant - you're getting an element by its ID `key`, then setting its ID attribute to `key`. That line of code literally does nothing.

Comment: @JackBashford - That line is in the branch guarded by an `if (!div)` condition. It's for when the div wasn't found by `getElementById`.

Comment: yes, that is what needs to be done!

Comment: @JackBashford - I am using this as a function. It is for firebase chat app and i am receiving the previous message in the chat box for which i need to pass on the ids so that every message comes one by one and throughout the process id(s) are passed on!

Answer (score 7):

`container.firstChild` returns the first child node within `container`, which may not be an element (it could be a text node, comment, etc.). If it's not an element, it won't have `setAttribute`. If you want the first *element* child, use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild).

---

Side note: `id` is a reflected property, so you can write `div.id = key;` rather than `div.setAttribute("id", key);`. They do the same thing. (This is true of many attributes, but not all; `value` on `input` elements is a major exception, it's *not* an accessor for the `value` attribute.)

Comment: firstElementChild didn't work, but div['id'] did worked for me! Still I am facing new errors but this doesn't seem to be right way to do it!